# How to correctly set / get departmentNumber property in Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've been trying to read and set the **departmentNumber** property for a **DirectoryEntry** object using C#, but I always have the problem that using ADSI Edit I cannot see that anything in this entry was changed.

Approaches I've tried so far include:

```
directoryEntry.Properties["departmentNumber"].Value = new object[]{ "SomeContent" };
```

and

```
directoryEntry.InvokeSet("departmentNumber", new object[]{ "SomeContent" };
```

and

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("PutEx", new object[]{ 2, "departmentNumber", new object[]{"SomeContent"}});
```

and

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("Put", new object[]{ "departmentNumber", "SomeContent" });
```

**Update**
All of the above followed by *directoryEntry.CommitChanges();*.

No matter what I try, I do (with some of the examples above) get results in terms of being able to read the value again using corresponding code, but whenever I use the ADSI-Editor and look at the properties of the user, I cannot see that departmentNumber contains any data.

If I set the property to a certain value using ADSI-Editor, I also cannot query that particular value via C#, but what I can do is to use a very simple VB script as below:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=........")
objUser.GetInfo
objUser.PutEx 2, "departmentNumber", Array("SomeContent")
```

This does change the value of the property that I can see in the ADSI-Editor, but again, using C# I cannot read it.

What is the problem here, and why does it look as if there are two different "departmentNumber" properties? Despite trying to find someone with the same problem I didn't come up with any answers or even pointers in the right direction, so any help is greatly appreciated. Please also ask in case you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to commit changes. It's necessary usin ADSI. Here is an example of a user création and modification :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  /* Connection to Active Directory
   */
  DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.225.100:389/OU=SousMonou,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr", "jpb", "pwd");

  /* User creation
  */
  DirectoryEntry auser = deBase.Children.Add("cn=a User", "user");
  auser.CommitChanges();

  auser.Properties["samaccountname"].Value = "AUser";
  auser.Properties["givenName"].Value = "A";
  auser.Properties["sn"].Value = "User";
  auser.Properties["displayName"].Value = "AUser";
  auser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = "AUser@dom.fr";
  auser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
  auser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 544;

  auser.CommitChanges();

  /* Retreiving the user
  */
  DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(&(cn=a User))";
  dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

  SearchResult srUser = dsLookForDomain.FindOne();
  if (srUser != null)
  {
    DirectoryEntry deUser = srUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
    deUser.Properties["departmentNumber"].Value = "Test Department";
    deUser.CommitChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work - I have that in my code but forgot to post it in the original question, will update it now. It might be the case that the AD on the particular server we use for testing is messed up, will try to verify that using a different machine today.

Comment: This just work with a user which is allowed to create a using into an OU in all my servers (from W2K3 to W2K8R2). Do you get some errors ?

Comment: No, didn't get any errors. Due to the fact that the AD structure on that particular machine was messed up (we only found out today) we had the behaviour I described above in my original question. As your suggestion provides a working example I accept this as the answer.